# Matlab:Specific number of streamlines

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, streamline

I have written the code for showing streamlines using the streamslice function. Since using streamline function shows only the lines but not direction, so I have used streamslice. But now I just want to show only four streamlines on the graph.Is it possible to do this using streamslice?

```
clear all
syms x y
[x,y]=meshgrid(-1:0.1:3,-1:0.1:3.5); 
uu=x; vv=x.*(x-1).*(y+1);
streamslice(x,y,uu,vv)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add density for this.

```
streamslice(...,density)
```

when density is higher then 0. the default is 1.